# Transaction not found waiting to be added to mempool

Tags: mempool, lost-transactions

Why does my Bitcoin withdrawal say "Transaction not found, waiting for it to appear in the mempool"?

Comment: Mines been doing the same thing for almost 3 hours now. How did you get your transaction refunded or sent into the mempool?

Comment: Mines been like this for the last 10 hours. SMH.

Comment: Hi Randall and Ktrey, please see Andrew’s answer below and especially https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/48884

Answer (score 3):

There are currently a lot of unconfirmed transactions on the network, so much so that many nodes have reached their configured maximum mempool size. Nodes that have hit this limit have started removing transactions from their mempools and increasing the minimum fee rate required in order to be added to that node's mempool and be relayed to other nodes it is connected to.

Given that this is the current situation, it is likely that your transaction does not pay a high enough fee rate to be added to many nodes' mempools, so it is not propagating around the network.

Comment: So what do I do it's still doing that's 24 hrs later
Thank you so much for answering me

Comment: @ErinTrujillo https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/48884 may help you.